# Breeze Type Error: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze

I have a EF Code-First DB, with 3 important Tables. Share, ContactDetail and Owner. The Share and the Owner Tables both have the Contact Detail as navigational property, but the Share Table has both ContactDetail and Owner as navigational properties.

I have a simple controller Get that retrieves the Shares

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Share> VesselShares()
{
   return _cp.Context.Shares;
}
```

and the breeze call is:

```
    getVesselShares = function (vId) {
            var query = EntityQuery.from('VesselShares')
                .expand('Owner, ContactDetail')
                .where('VesselId', filterQueryOp.Equals, vId)
                .orderBy(orderBy.share);

            return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                return vesselShares(data.results);
            }
        }
```

When I load my page, with some other data:

```
return ctx.getVesselById(vId, vessel).then(function () {

            ctx.getVesselShares(vId).then(function() {
                logger.log('Data Loaded: ' + ctx.vesselShares().length, 'shipdetail', 'Ship', true);
            });

            ////Load all the details before activating the other child pages
            //return Q.all([
            //    //ctx.getVesselShareOwners(vId, dbShareOwners),
            //    //ctx.getVesselVesselBuilders(vId),
            //    //ctx.getVesselAlterations(vId),
            //    //ctx.getVesselInsurers(vId),
            //    //ctx.getVesselClassifSocieties(vId),
            //    ctx.getVesselShares(vId)
            //]).then(function () {
            //    //shareOwners(utils.consolidateShares(dbShareOwners()));
            //    logger.log('Data Loaded: ' + ctx.vesselShares().length, 'shipdetail', 'Ship', true);
            //    //register.shareOwners(shareOwners());
            //    //ctx.vesselShareOwners(shareOwners());
            //    ////Can only Register when all 64 Shares are occupied
            //    //ctx.canRegisterVessel(dbShareOwners().length === 64);
            //});
        });
```

The first call to retrieve the Shares work fine, but oddly the 2nd call and subsequent calls throw an error on the **ctx.getVesselShares** method.

> ***"TypeError: object is not a function"*** .

I was able to track down the error to this line of code in the breeze.debug.js...

```
proto.getProperty = function (propertyName) {
  return this[propertyName]();
};
```

This method is expecting a **ContactDetail** observable but strangely breeze doesn't come with an observable on those subsequent calls.

This error happens whenever I want to saveChanges or retrieve records on the Share Table. I'm running the latest breeze, MVC 5, Web Api 2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is `contactDetail` in your Knockout code? Is there anything that changes its value?

Comment: No. Nothing on page load changes the contactDetail. But when saving a new contact, it is created... after page load, it throws the same error during save.